# TeamCity: Disable build trigger for all TeamCity projects

Tags: teamcity

I would like to ask is there any way to disable build triggers for all TeamCity projects by running a script?

I have a scenario that I need to disable all the build triggers to prevent the builds from running. This is because sometimes, I might need to perform some upgrading process on build agent machines which will take more than one day.

I do not wish to manually click on Disable buttons for every build triggers on every different TeamCity projects. Is there a way to automate this process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Team City REST API.

Given your Team City is deployed at *http://dummyhost.com* and you enabled guest access with system admin role (otherwise just switch from *guestAuth* to *httpAuth* in URL and specify user with password in request, details are in documentation) you can do next:

1. Get all build configurations
   `GET http://dummyhost.com/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/`
2. For each build configuration get all triggers
   `GET http://dummyhost.com/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:***YOUR_BUILD_CONFIGID***/triggers/`
3. For each trigger disable it
   `PUT http://dummyhost.com/guestAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:***YOUR_BUILD_CONFIGID***/triggers/***YOUR_TRIGGER_ID***/disabled`

See full documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API)

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much for the great reply. This is exactly what I am looking for using TeamCity RestAPI.

Comment: Note: if not authorized (e.g. through httpAuth), the error message for TeamCity version 10 is that `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported`. When logged in, PUT'ing to the mentioned URL works like charm.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here is working script exaple with proper authorization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43998789/603516

Answer (score 4):

You can pause the build queue. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xyzc0hw40J0). This way you needn't touch the build configurations at all; you're just bringing the TC to a halt.

For agent-specific upgrades, it's best to disable only the agent you're working on. See [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Agents+Configuration+and+Maintenance#BuildAgentsConfigurationandMaintenance-Enabling/DisablingAgentsviaUI).

Neither of these is "by running a script" as you asked, but I take it you were only asking for a scripted solution to avoid a lot of GUI clicking.

Comment: thanks for the reply. You are right, i am looking for a scripted solution that can automate this manual process. Is there any way that we can develop a script to get xml tag that hold build trigger settings and change it to disable the triggers? just curious

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to simply disable the agent, so no more builds will run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script to bulk pause all (still not paused) build configurations by project name pattern via TeamCity REST API:

```
TEAMCITY_HOST=http://teamcity.company.com
CREDS="-u domain\user:password"
curl $CREDS --request GET "$TEAMCITY_HOST/app/rest/buildTypes/" \
| sed -r "s/(<buildType)/\n\\1/g" | grep "Project Name Regex" \
| grep -v 'paused="true"' | grep -Po '(?<=buildType id=")[^"]*' \
| xargs -I {} curl -v $CREDS --request PUT "$TEAMCITY_HOST/app/rest/buildTypes/id:{}/paused" --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "true"
```

Comment: This disables the whole configuration and not the triggers

Answer (score 0):

At least since TeamCity 2021.2.3 (build 99711, the version that I use), build triggers can be disabled with one click.

[image]